# How to pass variable to new method I call when using @selector(methodname)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, selector

Ok very quick question. I am adding annotations to my iOS using MKMapAnnotation.  I create a int and an annotation with a disclosure button Which calls the method loadPano like so:

```
int integervariable;
[disclosureButton addTarget:self 
                     action:@selector(loadPano) 
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now say I want to access the integer variable in the method load pano how would I do this, I am struggling to understand how I would pass the variable to the new method when it is called like the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have to pass an integer associated to each disclosurebutton, you can set `disclosurebutton.tag = integer value;`.

Sort of hacky to pass data around in tags but in simple cases it works.

Also for this to work, declare `loadpano` this way:

```
- (void)loadPano:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSInteger relevantInteger = sender.tag;
   // More code here
}
```

And set the target like this:

```
[disclosureButton addTarget:self 
                     action:@selector(loadPano:) 
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Note that the method now takes a parameter so the selector includes a  colon.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but how would you go about accessing that tag in the loadPano method?

Comment: Perfect mate nice trick! I could't declare it as a property due to it being changed elsewhere. Thanks for the big help and everyone else who answered!

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions:

1. Use the tag. But this can only be an integer.
2. Add an instance variable (probably accessed using a property) to the class of the button. That means you must make a custom class for the button.
3. Most general: Use associated objects (a.k.a. associative references), using the runtime functions `objc_setAssociatedObject()` and `objc_getAssociatedObject()`

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass values other than sender and eventType in target-action methods.

**The action message may optionally include the sender and the event as parameters, in that order.**

If that integerVariable is a constant, then you can set it as a tag for the control from which you are initiating that action (in your case it is disclosureButton).

or

You can take an instance variable in your class, and access that value in loadPano method.

Answer (score -1):

In the general case, you can create an instance of `NSInvocation` with your target, selector, and whatever parameters it needs. Then you call the invocation's `-invoke` method to send the message to the target.

Comment: how does this help the question?

Comment: @newacct The root of the OP's question seems to be how one can call a method that takes parameters using a selector; the question title is *How to pass variable to new method I call when using @selector(methodname)*. `NSInvocation` offers a solution for that. I said "in the general case" because despite the title it sounds like the OP isn't really making the call, but only registering assigning a target and action.

Comment: It seems that the OP is trying to pass context information to the callback for his button, and since the API only allows him to pass a target and selector, he falsely believes that this requires some magical syntax in the language that allows him to "stuff" that context information into the selector or "fix" the argument to the selector. I believe that's why he titled the question the way he did.